# How can you autofill conditional formatting on Google Sheet with data anchored on one cell?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have conditional formatting on cell B2 based on data in cell B100. ex: Custom Formula is

```
=B2>B100
```

I would like to autofill conditional formatting for all subsequent cells in column B based also on B100. ex: Custom Formula is

```
=B3>B100
=B4>B100
=B5>B100
ETC
```

**ALSO,** would like to autofill the same conditional formatting across other columns. ex: Custom Formula is

```
=c3>c100   =d3>d100
=c4>c100   =d4>d100
=c5>c100   =d5>d100
ETC
```

I want to autofill this conditional formatting so I don't have to do each cell by hand; I have about 450 cells I want to apply this formatting to.

Comment: Try `=B2>B$100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional formatting can be applied to a range. Write the custom formula as it should work for the upper left corner of the range, using relative and absolute references as needed (`=B2>B$100`, given by Scott Craner in a comment).

When this formula is applied to, say, 7th row, it will work as `=B7>B$100`.

Comment: I've tried using the anchor B$100 but the conditional formatting does not follow a subsequent series IE   B3>B$100, B4>B$100 it just pastes the same formula B2>B$100 on every cell. Working on Google Sheet if that makes a difference.

Comment: You don't copy-paste anything; just select a range and enter conditional formatting rule for it. It will display with B2, but it will work using relative references.

Comment: I see. Seeing B2 threw me off thinking it was only pasting the original, but checked and you are right it does use relative references.